# rgdal failing on Windows with a URL specifying GeoJSON

Tags: r, gdal

```
devtools::install_github("SeaAroundUs/rseaaroundus")
library("seaaroundus")
regionmap("eez")

#> Error in ogrListLayers(url): Cannot open data source
```

Internally `regionmap()` is using the url `http://api.seaaroundus.org/api/v1/eez/?geojson=true` in a call to `readOGR(dsn=url, layer=ogrListLayers(url))`

`ogrListLayers` fails, but even if you get they layer (`OGRGeoJSON`) specified manually, `readOGR()` fails with `Cannot open file`

Any help greatly appreciated. I'm not a windows user, so not sure where things are going wrong.

Using: `rgdal v1.1.1`, `GDAL v.1.11.2`, `R v.3.2.3`, on Windows XP

There's no problem on *nix systems